# Can't understand why a certain space is not complete?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider the normed vector space
$$
X:= \{x = (x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \ | \ \exists \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \forall \ i \in \mathbb{N} \ : \ i \ge n \implies x_i =0 \},
$$
with the supremeum norm $||x|| := \sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}|x_i|$. I read that this is not complete, but that it is a linear subspace of $l^\infty$ whose closure is the subspace of sequences of real numbers that converge to zero.

But I can't see how this space is not equal to its closure, and hence complete. Every element in the space converges to $X$ eventually so it seems every Cauchy sequence in $X$ converges to a point in $X$? If not is not a complete space, then what is an example of a limit point of $X$ that is not in $X$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your space is essentially all sequences whose terms are zero after some finite stage.

Consider the sequence $x_i$ where $x_i$ is the sequence $(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\cdots,\frac{1}{i},0,0\cdots)$ and $0$s for the rest.

So the sequence goes $$(1,0,\cdots),(1,\frac{1}{2},0,\cdots),(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},0,\cdots) $$

**Work for you to do:** Can you check that this sequence is cauchy and WANTS to converge to the sequence$(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}\cdots)$ but this is not an element of your space?

**Edit:** Thanks to users Gregory Grant and tree detective for fixing my original mistake. I thought that the norm had something to do with the index of the first non-zero entry, whereas it has to do with the magnitude of it.

Comment: How is that Cauchy?  The difference of any two always has a $1$ in some component and therefore the sup norm of the difference is one.

Comment: Better take $(1, \frac{1}{2}, \ldots, \frac{1}{n}, 0, 0,  \ldots)$

Comment: Ah good point! Thank you!

Comment: @treedetective That seems to work

Comment: @eurocoder Sorry, that is an artifact from a mistake I made. It is fixed!